# How do I flag date time index for a certain set of time in pandas?

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a large `pandas` data frame with a date-time object as the index.  Each day represented is broken up into 5 minute increments.  The index is in the `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00` format.

How do I create a flag for everything before 10:00 am and after 2:00 pm?

I tried the following:

```
import pandas
import numpy

condition = [df.index() <= "10:00:00"]
replace = 1
df['early_flag'] = np.select(condition, replace, default = 0)
```

I get an error that states `Datetimeindex object is not callable.

Data looks as such:

```
datetime              id    name
2004-04-01 09:45:00    5    bypedal
2004-04-01 09:50:00    5    bypedal
2004-04-01 09:55:00    5    bypedal
2004-04-01 10:00:00    5    bypedal
2004-04-01 10:05:00    5    bypedal
```

The outcome I'm looking for is such:

```
datetime              id    name      Early_Flag
2004-04-01 09:45:00    5    bypedal    1
2004-04-01 09:50:00    5    bypedal    1
2004-04-01 09:55:00    5    bypedal    1
2004-04-01 10:00:00    5    bypedal    0
2004-04-01 10:05:00    5    bypedal    0
```

Comment: can you provide some sample data please?

Comment: `df.index` is not callable no `()` after index.

Comment: Data sample added.   Thanks @HenryEcker.  Is there a way to do this with multiple days having the same times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `time` accessor of the datetime index + [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
from datetime import time

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# modified sample data to demonstrate multiple days and both bounds
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': ['2004-04-01 09:45:00', '2004-04-02 09:50:00',
                 '2004-04-03 09:55:00', '2004-04-04 10:00:00',
                 '2004-04-05 10:05:00', '2004-04-06 13:05:00',
                 '2004-04-07 14:00:00', '2004-04-07 14:00:01'],
    'id': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    'name': ['bypedal', 'bypedal', 'bypedal', 'bypedal', 'bypedal', 'bypedal',
             'bypedal', 'bypedal']
})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')

df['Early_flag'] = np.where(
    (df.index.time < time(10, 0)) | (df.index.time > time(14, 0)),
    1,
    0
)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
                     id     name  Early_flag
datetime                                    
2004-04-01 09:45:00   5  bypedal           1
2004-04-02 09:50:00   5  bypedal           1
2004-04-03 09:55:00   5  bypedal           1
2004-04-04 10:00:00   5  bypedal           0
2004-04-05 10:05:00   5  bypedal           0
2004-04-06 13:05:00   5  bypedal           0
2004-04-07 14:00:00   5  bypedal           0
2004-04-07 14:00:01   5  bypedal           1
```

Comment: Thank you.  Last question...what if i want it before a half hour point...like 10:30?

Comment: Just change the time you're comparing it to `time(10, 30)`.